# Option to Register for COM Interop greyed out

Tags: c#, com

I have created a .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package in c# and now I have been asked to make it accessible from C++. I have no experience in this, but I thought I should use COM. Under Properties -> Build, the option to register for COM interop is greyed. I assume my project is somehow incompatible with this option. What can I do to get this option available?

Comment: COM can make .NET class accessible to C++ yes (and to other COM-compatible languages). But you cannot expose any .NET class to COM, it has to be special and is restricted to using certain .NET COM-compatible types. Maybe the easier would be to write another .NET (Framework or Core/5) assembly, wrapping the .NET standard 2 one, but specialized for COM, so you don't change your existing code. Good starting point : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/example-com-class

Comment: See [Exposing .NET Core components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com) on how to expose your classes to COM.